# Unexpected horizontal line by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I drawed a plot with points and a horizontal line. Below is the example code:

```
dt <- data.frame(ID = c("Line",
                        "P1",
                        "P2",
                        "P3"),
                 Year = "2016",
                 Value = c(1, 0.533, 1.233, 0.233))

dt$Value <- format(dt$Value, digits = 2)

library(ggplot2)
# Unexpected horizontal line
ggplot(NULL) +
  geom_point(data = subset(dt, ID != "Line"),
             aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = ID, shape = ID)) + 
  geom_text(data = subset(dt, ID != "Line"),
            aes(label = subset(dt, ID != "Line")$Value,
                x = Year, y = Value)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(subset(dt, ID == "Line")$Value),
             color = "red") +
  theme_bw()
```

However, the Figure below seems strange: the red horizontal line is on the y-axis of 0.23, not 1. Why does this happen? Thanks!

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `format` would turn `Value` into character type, therefore `ggplot` no longer recognise it as continuous. You need to plot the graph using a numeric y-axis, then play around with the text labels and y-axis breaks for your desired formatting (note I created a `Value2` column for storing formatted character `Value`).

```r
library(ggplot2)

dt <- data.frame(ID = c("Line",
                        "P1",
                        "P2",
                        "P3"),
                 Year = "2016",
                 Value = c(1, 0.533, 1.233, 0.233))

dt$Value2 <- format(dt$Value, digits = 2)

# Unexpected horizontal line
ggplot(NULL) +
  geom_point(data = subset(dt, ID != "Line"),
             aes(x = Year, y = Value, color = ID, shape = ID)) + 
  geom_text(data = subset(dt, ID != "Line"),
            aes(label = Value2,
                x = Year, y = Value)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = subset(dt, ID == "Line")$Value,
             color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(dt$Value2[dt$ID != "Line"])) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think OP should round the plotted values. Most likely, the just want to format the text labels.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment, you are probably right. I have modified my answer a bit, let's see if OP is satisfied with it!